# Find children users from two levels

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of users, most of the users have column `parent_id` set, that describes the ID of his parent. From that information, I want to generate a table for current user to display all his children and simultaneously all their children (2 levels). It's the most basic query to select all of users children, but I don't know how to select their children too in one query, I tried different kinds of unions but mostly got empty or malformed results, Im not very experienced with more complicated SQL queries.

I made a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38298b/1) of a minimal example. In the result, I would like to display user "BBB" as a child of "AAA" and also "CCC", because it's a child of a child of "AAA" (current user)

Thank you for any help

Sample data:

```
id  | nickname | parent_id
1   |   AAA    |   null
2   |   BBB    |    1
3   |   CCC    |    2
```

Desired result for user AAA would be:

```
id  | nickname | parent_id
2   |   BBB         1
3   |   CCC    |    2
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results *in your question as text tables* would be a big help.

Comment: Sorry, I made an edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you describe, this may do what you want:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
WHERE u.parentid = ?
UNION ALL
SELECT uc.*
FROM users u JOIN
     users uc
     ON uc.parentid = u.id
WHERE u.parentid = ?;
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response, this works as a charm.

Answer (score 0):

With a cross join of the table to the id of the queried user:

```
select u.* 
from users u cross join (select id from users where nickname = 'AAA') p
where u.parent_id = p.id
   or u.parent_id in (select id from users where parent_id = p.id)
```

This way you supply only once the `nickname` of the user you query.
 
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eA4iw1gQTFN2hECyL1tuHa/1).
Results:

```
| id  | nickname | parent_id |
| --- | -------- | --------- |
| 2   | BBB      | 1         |
| 3   | CCC      | 2         |
```